# change single quotes to double quotes in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

input=

```
list1=[{'Name':'Jack','email':'xyz@foo.com'},
          {'Name':'Sam','email':'sam@xyz.com'},
          {'Name':'Dan','email':'dan@xyz.com'}]
```

Required output =

```
list1=[{"Name":"Jac","email":"xyz@foo.com"},
          {"Name":"Sam","email":"sam@xyz.com"},
          {"Name":"Dan","email":"dan@xyz.com"}]
```

How to get this as output? I've tried

```
list2=[]

for items in response:
    list2.append(json.dumps(items))
```

output I'm getting is

```
['{'Name':'Jack','email':'xyz@foo.com'}',
          '{'Name':'Sam','email':'sam@xyz.com'}',
          '{'Name':'Dan','email':'dan@xyz.com'}']
```

Comment: take your dictionary, dump it in a text editor an find-replace them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `json.dumps` like this:

```
import json

list1=[{'Name':'Jack','email':'xyz@foo.com'},
          {'Name':'Sam','email':'sam@xyz.com'},
          {'Name':'Dan','email':'dan@xyz.com'}]

print(list1)

list2 = json.dumps(list1)
print(list2)

#[{'Name': 'Jack', 'email': 'xyz@foo.com'}, {'Name': 'Sam', 'email': 'sam@xyz.com'}, {'Name': 'Dan', 'email': 'dan@xyz.com'}]
#[{"Name": "Jack", "email": "xyz@foo.com"}, {"Name": "Sam", "email": "sam@xyz.com"}, {"Name": "Dan", "email": "dan@xyz.com"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to do `json.dumps()` on the whole data structure, not on individual pieces.

It's not clear from your question what form the input is; is it a data structure in a file, or in memory?

If it's in a file, the first step will be reading it, so it's in memory, and so each part has the right form.

Once that's done, you can do `json.dumps()` on the whole list.

Comment: I'm getting this data in memory and when  I  do ```json.dumps()```  on whole list.
output =
```'[{"Name":"Jac","email":"xyz@foo.com"},
          {"Name":"Sam","email":"sam@xyz.com"},
          {"Name":"Dan","email":"dan@xyz.com"}]'```

Comment: That sounds like what you wanted!